# If $u=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi$ then $\operatorname{rk}(u)=\operatorname{rk}(L)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$u\in \mathcal L(E,F)$ with $E$ and $V$ finite vector spaces over $K$. If $\Phi:E\to K^n$ and $\Psi:F\to K^p$ are isomorphisms, and if $$u=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi,$$
with $L:K^n\to K^p$ linear, then $\operatorname{rk}(u)=\operatorname{rk}(L)$. I recall that $\operatorname{rk}(u)=\dim \operatorname{Im}(u)$.

How can I prove this result ? I tried to proove that $\operatorname{Im}(u)=\operatorname{Im}(L)$, but it didn't work...

Comment: $Im(u)$ can't be equal to $Im(L)$, because they don't belong to the same vector space in general. You can use for example obvious formulas like $rg(v\circ u) = rg(u)-\dim(ker(v)\cap Im(u))$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\im}{\text{Im}}$

$\im(u)$ and $\im(L)$ will indeed be isomorphic, but not equal in general.

Let $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ a basis of $F$ and $\{e_1,...,e_r\}$ a basis of $E$. You will have that $$\{\Phi(e_1),...,\Phi(e_n)\}$$
is a basis of $K^n$. Suppose that $rg(L)=m$ and suppose WLOG that $$\{L(\Phi(e_1)),...,L(\Phi(e_m))\},$$
is a basis of $\im(L)$. Since $\psi^{-1}$ is bijective, then $$\{\Psi^{-1}L(\Phi(e_1)),...,\Psi^{-1}L(\Phi(e_m))\}=\{u(e_1),...,u(e_m)\},$$
is a basis of $\im(u)$.